# How to define a var in PHP coming from jquery

Tags: php, jquery

So i already asked some questions here and fixed my problems,but i think they are growing instead of going down,lol.My problem now is i get "`Undefined index`" error.I will leave picture with the error [here](http://prntscr.com/dvgzj6).I tried to add variables to define my fsearch.Tried things like

`$fsearch = mysqli_escape_string($connect, $_POST['fsearch']);`

And more simple like.

```
$fsearch = $_POST['fsearch'];
```

But it doesn't work.Here is code.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
 $("#food_search").keyup(function(event){
  var search_term =$(this).val();
$.ajax({
 type:"POST",
 url:"/Food-Search",
 data:{fsearch:search_term},
 success:function(res){
  $("#food_search_result").html(res);
 },
 error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
           alert(xhr.status);
           alert(xhr.responseText);
           alert(thrownError);
       }
        });
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!----------------------------------------------------------------
                              HTML
----------------------------------------------------------------->

<form method="POST">
<p>Търсене на храни: <input type="text" name="fsearch" id="food_search"></p>
</form>
<!----------------------------------------------------------------
                             PHP
-----------------------------------------------------------------><?php

$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "name";
$password = "password";
$databaseName = "dbName";
$connect = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $databaseName);

if (!empty($_POST['fsearch'])) {
   $fsearch = mysqli_escape_string($connect, $_POST['fsearch']);
   $req = $connect->prepare('SELECT * FROM food_data_bg WHERE title LIKE "%".$fsearch."%"');
   $req->execute(array(
     'fsearch'=>'%'.$_POST['fsearch'].'%'
));
   if($req->rowCount()==0){
    echo 'Не бяха намерени резултати!';
}
else{
while($foodsearch=$req->fetch()){
?>
<div class="search-result">
    <img src="<?php echo $data['fimage']; ?>" class="fimage"/>
    <span class="result-title"><?php echo $data['title'];?></span><br>
    <span class="calories-total"><?php echo $data['calories total'];?></span><br>
</div>
<?php
}
}
}
?>
```

The code is used for searching,it must get the value of `#food-search` (input field) on every keyup and send it to PHP,which must check for matches in database and print it.(I think i got 1 more mistake by printing result in PHP page and returning it to java to print it in `#food_search_result` div)

Comment: Ajax call is fine. It seems to be some error in the page or the content.check your response using the console.

Comment: All is fine in console..http://prntscr.com/dvhe5o there is a picture of result(in console) No other errors are given,only the 2 which i gave up in my question ;/

Comment: your response status is zero. That means the no data returning from the request.Try to send data from form to the page via POST request. Thats how you can find out whats returning from the page. I am pretty sure that will be a blank page.

Comment: Isn't the ajax returning the information and posting it to #food_search_result div,or i should send data from form to page with another post;/

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this helps.**

PHP Code

```
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$databaseName = "stackoverflow";
if (!empty($_POST['fsearch'])) {    
$fsearch = $_POST['fsearch'];
$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname , $username, $password, $databaseName); 
if($mysqli->connect_error)
{
die("$mysqli->connect_errno: $mysqli->connect_error");
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM food_data_bg where title LIKE ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
if(!$stmt->prepare($query))
{
print "Failed to prepare statement\n";
}
else
{
$searchVar = "%" . $fsearch . "%";
$stmt->bind_param("s", $searchVar);

$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

if(!$result->num_rows){
echo 'Не бяха намерени резултати!';
}       
while ($row = $result->fetch_array())
{            
?>
<div class="search-result" style='clear:both; border:1px solid red;'>
<img src="<?php //echo $row['fimage']; ?>" class="fimage"/>
<span class="result-title"><?php echo $row['title'];?></span><br>
<span class="calories-total"><?php echo $row['calories total'];?></span><br>
</div>
<?php        
}     
}
$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();
}
```

HTML Code

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { 
    $("#food_search").keyup(function(event){
        var search_term =$(this).val();
        console.log(search_term);
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"Food-Search.php",
    data:{fsearch:search_term},
    success:function(res){
        $("#food_search_result").html(res);
        console.log(res);
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
           alert(xhr.status);
           alert(xhr.responseText);
           alert(thrownError);
       }
        });
    });
});
</script>

<!----------------------------------------------------------------
                              HTML
----------------------------------------------------------------->



<form method="POST">
<p>Търсене на храни: <input type="text" name="fsearch" id="food_search"></p>
</form>
<!----------------------------------------------------------------
                             PHP
----------------------------------------------------------------->

<div style="border:#FF0000;clear:both; padding:10px;min-height:300px;" id="food_search_result"></div>
```

Comment: Woah,thanks for your time to write that,but it is the same,exept there are no errors.Function isn't working again...

Comment: Pls share the PHP and MySQL version